# Table View when scrolling, custom cell is restoring and selected options are reassigned

Tags: ios, tableview, custom-cell

I have an requirement to display **list of questions and options**, so that the user can select his own option for every question and be able to submit.

When submitting answers they should be validated and the result will be displayed to the user.

I am using tableview. In my table view I am adding **custom cell** (**with multiple checkboxes** ) in `cellForRowIndexPath`.

The problem is when I am scrolling down the tableview, the **custom cell is restoring and selected options are assigned to another question**.

Comment: Please explain it more, may be with screenshot

Comment: first off all: **add your code!**

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, please post the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.  Please also take the time to use proper spelling and punctuation (and a meaningful title).

Comment: You should include your code so we are better able to find your problem.

From the sound of your explanation, I'm guessing you have added custom views to your cell, and when you reuse the cell, they still have info from the previous use on them. If you're adding subviews to your custom cell, make sure they are not hanging around in your cell when it gets reused.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store all information of each cell in an NSArray. You should have a Model Class, wich holds the information for one cell.
So every time a checkbox gets changed, you have to write that information into your array.
In your function `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you have to set the checkboxes with the values from your NSArray.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCustomCell *currentCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCustomCell"];
    currentCell.textLabel.text = self.myArray[indexPath.row].description;
    currentCell.switch1.on = self.myArray[indexPath.row].firstAnswer;
    currentCell.switch2.on = self.myArray[indexPath.row].secondAnswer;

    return currentCell;
}
```